# How to retain app EditText data when Android app process restarts

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

When we deny any permission in the settings page while our app is alive. Android kills our app. And re-create everything (fragments and activities). viewModel is also cleared. This cause the typed text in any edit text field gets cleared. FYI, While creating the fragment, the savedInstanceState will be non-null. But i see in some apps, like Gmail, Maps, the form data is retained while process restart. Can anyone please explain how to retain the edit text data while process recreate?

Answer (score 0):

You can retain `ViewModel` data using `SavedStateHandle`.

```
class MyViewModel(private val state: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() { ... }
```

`SavedStateHandle` is a key-value map where you can save your `EditText` content. The value will persist even after the process is killed by the System. You can retrieve the value using the same key.

To set the value:

```
savedStateHandle["text"] = text
```

and retrieve it back simply use the below statement:

```
savedStateHandle["text"]
```

Comment: is there any way other than doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    // store your data
    outState.putString("some code", "111")
    outState.putString("some code1", "222")
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // read your data
    savedInstanceState.getString("some code")
}
```